# Must HTTP Status Codes be strings?

Tags: openapi

The [`Responses`](https://swagger.io/specification/#responsesObject) object contains a {[HTTP Status Code](https://swagger.io/specification/#httpCodes): [`Response`](https://swagger.io/specification/#responseObject)} mapping.

In all the examples I found, the status code is provided as a string:

```js
{"200": {"description": "a pet to be returned"}}
```

I couldn't find any requirement for it to be a string and integers are accepted by the validators I tried.

All I found was [a PR changing from integer to string in all YAML examples](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/pull/500).

Should I only use strings?

Edit: In JSON, only strings are valid keys. So the question could be rephrased as "which of the following two assumptions is correct"?

- OpenAPI doesn't specify that HTTP Status Codes should be strings because that's implicit (JSON format). However, validation and display tools are being loose about that requirement.
- OpenAPI uses some kind of "JSON superset" in which integer keys are considered valid.

Comment: Technically, for JSON, the only valid key (in an object key value pair) is a string.
https://www.json.org/

Comment: Thanks @Oram. I edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this GH issue](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/1752), the keys must be strings:

> OpenAPI can be represented canonically in either JSON or YAML, as you say in JSON only strings can be keys. With regard to YAML:
>
> > This field MUST be enclosed in quotation marks (for example, "200") for compatibility between JSON and YAML.
>
> This has the effect that the key is always a string type.

This is not really a specification, but rather a requirement of the JSON format.